# Unable to understand competitive exam?

Tags: c, algorithm

I was giving a competition held yesterday. I was unable to solve the problem below.I saw a persons solution after competition ended and i am unable to understand .How he did it in so less time. What he applied. Please explain his solution.

> You are given two numbers `N` and `K` and a set `X`.
>
> `X = { x : x is a natural number ≤ N }` You have to find the total
>   number of pairs of elements `X[i]` and `X[j]` belonging to the given
>   set, such that, `i < j` and their sum is divisible by `K`.
>
> **Input Format:**
>
> An integer `T` followed by `T` lines, each containing a pair of space
>   separated integers `N` and `K`.
>
> **Output Format:**
>
> `T` integers on separate lines. Each integer denotes the answer
>   corresponding to that test case.
>
> **Constraints:**
>
> `1≤T≤100`
>
> `K≤N≤10^9`
>
> `1≤K≤10000`
>
> **Sample Input(Plaintext Link)**
>
> ```
> 2
> 10 4
> 7 3
> ```
>
> **Sample Output(Plaintext Link)**
>
> ```
> 10
> 7
> ```
>
> **Explanation**
>
> For the 1st test case, there are 10 pairs whose sum is divisible by 4.
>   (1,3), (1,7), (2,6), (2,10), (3,5), (3,9), (4,8), (5,7), (6,10) and
>   (7,9)
>
> For the 2nd test case, there are 7 pairs whose sum is divisible by 3.
>   (1,2), (1,5), (2,4), (2,7), (3,6), (4,5) and (5,7)

Solutions--

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main()
{
    long long int t,n,m,x,y,c=0;
    scanf("%lld",&t);
    while(t--)
    {
        scanf("%lld %lld",&n,&m);
        c=0;
        x=n/m;
        y=n%m;
            c+=((x*x*(m-1)-((m%2==0)?x:0))+x*(x-1))/2+y*x;
            if(y>m/2)
            c+=y-m/2;
        printf("%lld\n",c);
    }
}
```

Comment: I removed Python and added C, because the code is obviously C.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hints**

Brute force approach:

You can write a double loop on `0<i<N` and `i<j≤N` and count the pairs such that `(i + j) % K == 0`.

Smarter approach:

For a given `i`, the number of `j` such that `(i + j) % K == 0` equals approximately `(N - i) / K`, as every `K`th number is a multiple of `K`. (It is up to you to refine the approximation to the exact expression.)

Yet smarter approach:

Using the previous result, you will need to sum the `(N - i)/K` contributions for all `i`. This expression remains constant for `K` successive values of `i`  and decreases from `i=1` (i.e. `~N/K`) to `i=N` (i.e. `0`), in steps of `1`. So the total count will be like `K.T(N/K)`, where `T(m)` denotes the `m`th triangular number, `m.(m+1)/2`.

(Again , it is up to you to refine the approximations to the exact value and find a closed formula.)

Example:

```
N=9, K=3

1 => *2*  3   4  *5*  6   7  *8*  9  => 3
2 =>      3  *4*  5   6  *7*  8   9  => 2
3 =>          4   5  *6*  7   8  *9* => 2
4 =>             *5*  6   7  *8*  9  => 2
5 =>                  6  *7*  8   9  => 1
6 =>                      7   8  *9* => 1
7 =>                         *8*  9  => 1
8 =>                              9  => 0
```